Async SQLAlchemy 2.0 missing Greenlet error
looking for some advice on using Async SQLAlchemy as I have been experienced this error with my code: sqlalchemy.exc.MissingGreenlet: greenlet_spawn has not been called; can't call await_only() here. Was IO attempted in an unexpected place? (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/xd2s)
I have 2 classes, a user class and a activity class. A user can have multiple activities while each activity can only have 1 user.
My code for post activities seem to always give me the greenlet_spawn error. I narrowed down the problem to the last return statement i.e. return activity_with_user. But I've been stuck with this for awhile and I'm looking for some help. Thanks in advance.
My Route to create an activity.
@router.post("/activity", response_model=ActivitySchema, status_code=201)
async def write_post(
    request: Request,
    current_user: Annotated[UserRead, Depends(get_current_user)],
    db: Annotated[AsyncSession, Depends(async_get_db)],
):
    # Query for the user based on their email
    result = await db.execute(select(User).where(User.email == current_user.email))
    db_user = result.scalars().first()

    if db_user is None:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="User not found")

    try:
        new_activity = Activity(user=db_user, ip_address="123.123.123.123")

        db.add(new_activity)
        await db.commit()

        result = await db.execute(
            select(Activity)
            .options(joinedload(Activity.user))
            .where(Activity.id == new_activity.id)
        )
        activity_with_user = result.scalars().first()
        print("activity_with_usage")

        return activity_with_user

    except Exception as e:
        await db.rollback()
        print(e)
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=f"Internal server error {e}")


Code to setup async database
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import create_async_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio.session import AsyncSession
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, MappedAsDataclass, sessionmaker
from typing import AsyncGenerator

from ..config import settings


# Inherit from DeclarativeBase and MappedAsDataclass for async ORM
class Base(DeclarativeBase, MappedAsDataclass):
    pass


DATABASE_URI = settings.POSTGRES_URI
DATABASE_PREFIX = settings.POSTGRES_ASYNC_PREFIX
DATABASE_URL = f"{DATABASE_PREFIX}{DATABASE_URI}"

# Create the async engine
# TODO: Set echo to False in production
async_engine = create_async_engine(DATABASE_URL, echo=False, future=True)

# Function to create a new session
local_session = sessionmaker(
    bind=async_engine, class_=AsyncSession, expire_on_commit=False
)


async def async_get_db() -> AsyncGenerator[AsyncSession, None]:
    async_session = local_session
    async with async_session() as db:
        yield db


Code for SQLAlchemy models
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    # Specify mapped for async ORM
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(
        "id",
        autoincrement=True,
        nullable=False,
        unique=True,
        primary_key=True,
        init=False,
    )

    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(30))


    usage: Mapped[List["Activity"]] = relationship(
        "Activity",
        back_populates="user",
        lazy="selectin",
    )

    email: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(50), unique=True, index=True)


class Activity(Base):
    __tablename__ = "activities"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(
        "id",
        autoincrement=True,
        nullable=False,
        unique=True,
        primary_key=True,
        init=False,
    )
    user_id = mapped_column(ForeignKey("users.id", ondelete="CASCADE"), index=True)
    ip_address: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(100))
    user: Mapped["User"] = relationship("User", back_populates="usage", lazy="selectin")


How is ActivitySchema defined? Given that you have a relation back to a list of activities in your user model - this is probably what the causes the error (since it's then trying to load the content, but is no longer awaited - since it's a lazy load)
